# Automate/Execute multiple ASP.NET Core commands

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core

How to automate/execute multiple ASP.NET Core commands in Visual Studio Code?

For example, execute `dotnet clean`,`dotnet restore`, `dotnet build` etc in a single go..

---

I was going to ask this question but instead **found a solution** for the same. So sharing this with the community.

Comment: When sharing your own learning, please try to extract the question and answer your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio Code to develop ASP.NET Core apps you can automate `dotnet restore`, `dotnet build`, `dotnet run`, `dotnet clean` commands using a short one with the help of `doskey`.

```
doskey c = dotnet clean
doskey b = dotnet build
doskey r = dotnet restore
doskey rr = dotnet run
doskey p = dotnet publish -c release -r centos.7-x64 (NOTE: Here centos is the target OS)
```

Now, by entering `c`, `b`, `r`, `rr` or `p` will execute their respective command(s) on the integrated terminal window of Visual Studio Code. You can bind multiple commands together using `$T`. For eg:

```
doskey cb = dotnet clean $T dotnet build $T echo ************ DONE ************
doskey crb = dotnet clean $T dotnet restore $T dotnet build $T echo ************ DONE ************
doskey crbr = dotnet clean $T dotnet restore $T dotnet build $T dotnet run $T echo ************ DONE ************
doskey crbp = dotnet clean $T dotnet restore $T dotnet build $T dotnet publish - c release -r centos.7-x64 $T echo ************ DONE ************
doskey cbp = dotnet clean $T dotnet build $T dotnet publish -c release -r centos.7-x64 $T echo ************ DONE ************
```

Entering `cb`, `crb`, `crbr`, `crbp` or `rbp` will execute their respective multi-command(s).

---

**These shortcuts will flush away when Visual Studio Code is restarted** so to keep them **persistent**, save these commands as a batch file(eg: *doskey.bat*), and then open your `usersettings.json` file in Visual Studio Code and add these lines (*these settings are for Command Prompt as terminal window*) :

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "/K C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\doskey.bat"
    // replace the path with your batch file, also remember to keep the "/K" flag
],
```