# How does a .NET Core console project runs on windows OS without *.exe file?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I've created a simple .NET core console app targeting .NET Core Framework 1.1. When I build it, it creates an assembly file named `DotNetCoreConsoleApp.dll` in the `\bin\debug` folder. So there is nothing that I can double click and run directly but interestingly when I start debugging the project by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> then Visual Studio is able to launch a process.

Project configuration of my project is as below:

[image]

How windows will be able to launch such an application process without any exe file? I understand that Windows only understands a file as starting point of a process if it contains [PE header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable).

Comment: Project is not setup to compile as library and still does not produce an exe (no core experience here)?

Comment: You need to publish it as per [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore2x).

Comment: @PatrickArtner I've added a snapshot into the post showing my project configuration.

Comment: Publish it using `dotnet publish -c release -r OSnameGoesHere`. Take a look at [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386585/automate-multiple-dotnet-core-commands/47386996#47386996) if in future you may develop in Visual Studio Code. I use VS Code and have successfully published for Windows OS, which creates an `.exe`

Comment: Here is some more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36516848/how-to-run-a-net-core-dll#36518972

Comment: @john publish process is also creating *.dll files only.

Comment: @RBT What about `dotnet publish -r win-x64`?

Comment: @RBT: thanks for sharing, that is most peculiar

Comment: @john this command `dotnet publish -r win-x64` results in error `error : Assets file 'C:\Users\rasik.bihari\source\repos\App1\DotNetCoreConsoleApp\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1/win-x64'. Ensure you have restored this project for TargetFramework='netcoreapp1.1' and RuntimeIdentifier='win-x64'. [C:\Users\rasik.bihari\source\repos\App1\DotNetCoreConsoleApp\DotNetCoreConsoleApp.csproj]`

Comment: I assumed you were doing restore first, since you said you had already tried publish? Run `dotnet restore -r win-x64` first, and then publish.

Comment: ok @john. So now the `dotnet publish -r win-x64` command worked after doing `dotnet restore -r win-x64` but it is still creating a dll file inside `\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\win-x64` directory.

Comment: @RBT The .exe is some kind of pre-built Microsoft wrapper around the DLL. As far as I can tell, it just looks for a DLL with the same name as itself, and then loads that and executes it. You can substitue the DLL to change the program that's executed. It's how things are now, it seems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no exe file.

From msdn:
"Short answer, there isn’t one.  When you compile your .NET Core console application for example, you get a DLL.  Then you execute it using the DOTNET command from the .NET Core SDK found here."

From a different answer on stackoverflow ([Visual Studio 2017 missing exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44201334/visual-studio-2017-missing-exe-file)):
You have two options:

1. If you want an EXE, you need to target the .NET Framework.
2. If you don't want to change your code, then you need to install .NET Core on the server and run dotnet pathToDll on a command line

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/03/07/net-core-application-where-is-my-exe-how-to-publish/